# Guardar archivo pdf en php y MYSQL

Tags: php

estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de guardar el archivo pdf. Tengo un listado de paciente y cada paciente tendrá un resultado que ese resultado se sube en forma de pdf, lo que estoy haciendo es que cuando se guarde el resultado pdf de cada paciente, se va a crear una carpeta con el nombre del paciente y adentro tiene que estar el PDF. No sé si se me entiende, el problema que tengo ahora es que me salta este error y no me guarda el PDF.

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function
> cannot be a directory in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Proyecto\modulos\turnos\pruebaguardar.php on
> line 33
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
> "C:\xampp\tmp\php5A25.tmp" to "archivo/AndresAlmiron" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Proyecto\modulos\turnos\pruebaguardar.php on
> line 33

```
<?php

require_once "../../class/turnos.php";
require_once "../../class/paciente.php";
require_once "../../class/MySQL.php";



$idturno = $_POST["idTurno"];
$archivo =$_FILES["archivo"];

$turnos=Turno::obtenerPorId($idturno);

$paciente = paciente::obtenerPorId($turnos->getIdPaciente());

$nombreApellido = $paciente->getNombre() . $paciente->getApellido();
$directorio = "archivo/$nombreApellido";


// Se obtiene el archivo que se quiere remplazar, y se lo remplaza por el nombre y apellido del paciente y el turno, y a que archivo se va a dar todos estos valores.
$nombreArchivo = str_replace($archivo['name'] , $paciente->getNombre() . $paciente->getApellido() . $idturno, $archivo['name'] );
$nombreArchivo = $nombreArchivo . ".pdf";


if (!file_exists($directorio)){
    mkdir($directorio,0777,true);
}

move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'],$directorio); (LINEA 33)


$database = new MySQL();

$sql = "INSERT INTO Archivos (id_archivo, nombre ) "
     . "VALUES (NULL, '{$nombreArchivo}')";

$database->insertar($sql);


?>[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
```

Comment: El error es bastante claro: El segundo parámetro no puede ser un directorio, debe ser un nombre de archivo, en este caso, incluyendo la ruta, algo como : `move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'], "$directorio/$nombreArchivo");`

Comment: Ahi me funciono, muchisimas gracias.